# Is there a way to fix this code to prevent runtime error?

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error, ms-access-2016

The code is suppose to insert into a table called log_time_tbl.
log_time_tbl:
[image: This is what log_time_tbl looks like]

I've run into a **Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 1.**

Most of the code works I just keep running into a problem with this segment of code:

```
'Insert a new record in log_time_tbl
 db.Execute "INSERT INTO log_time_tbl " & "([GO info], [worker name], [phase], [start time], [end time], [Time Elapsed]) VALUES " & "(" & Forms("Tech_frm").GO_list.ItemData(selectedGO) & ", '" & Forms("Tech_frm").signin_txt.Value & "', '" & Forms("Tech_frm").phase_combo.Value & "', #" & startTime & "#, #" & startTime & "#, #" & startTime & "#);"
```

Here is all of the code for the section. ALL the nk message boxes pop up the correct information. So I believe that the insert function is written wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
Private Sub Start_btn_Click()
    Dim nk As Integer
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim selectedGO As Variant
    Dim techName As String
    Dim workPosition As String
    Dim startTime As Date
    Dim b As Byte
    

    ' Check if phase_combo is null
    If IsNull(Me.phase_combo.Value) Then
        nk = MsgBox("Please select a Phase and Try Again", vbCritical, "Phase Not Selected")
    Else
        If Me.GO_list.ListIndex = -1 Then
            nk = MsgBox("Please select a G.O.# and Try Again", vbCritical, "G.O.# Not Selected")
        Else
            nk = MsgBox("GO Numbers were Selected", vbInformation, "No missing data")
            Set db = CurrentDb()
            Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("log_time_tbl")
            
            ' Get technician name from tech_combo on Login_frm
            techName = Forms("Tech_frm").signin_txt.Value
            
            ' Get work position from work_position combo box on Tech_form
            workPosition = Forms("Tech_frm").phase_combo.Value
            
            ' Get current time
            startTime = Now()
            
            'make sure multiselect is on for the go list
            'b = Forms("Tech_frm").Controls("GO_list").MultiSelect
            'nk = MsgBox("output: " & b, vbInformation, "MultiSelect output")
            'nk = MsgBox("Selected Tech Name: " & Forms("Tech_frm").signin_txt.Value & "Selected Phase: " & Forms("Tech_frm").phase_combo.Value, vbInformation, "Tech/Phase")
            
            'DOESNT WORK
            'For Each selectedGO In Forms("Tech_frm").GO_list.ItemsSelected
            'nk = MsgBox("Selected G.O.#: " & Forms("Tech_frm").GO_list.ItemData(selectedGO), vbInformation, "GO#")
                'DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO log_time_tbl (GO_info) values ([Forms(Tech_frm]).GO_list.ItemData(selectedGO)")

                      
            'BREAKES HERE Loop through selected items in GO_list on Tech_form
            For Each selectedGO In Forms("Tech_frm").GO_list.ItemsSelected
            
            'Check to see if the tech name, phase, and GO is being pulled
            nk = MsgBox("Selected Tech Name: " & Forms("Tech_frm").signin_txt.Value & "Selected Phase: " & Forms("Tech_frm").phase_combo.Value, vbInformation, "Tech/Phase")
            nk = MsgBox("Selected G.O.#: " & Forms("Tech_frm").GO_list.ItemData(selectedGO), vbInformation, "GO#")
                
                'set the value of the GO to a varible name
               selectedGOValue = Forms("Tech_frm").GO_list.ItemData(selectedGO)
               
                'Insert a new record in log_time_tbl
                db.Execute "INSERT INTO log_time_tbl " & "([GO info], [worker name], [phase], [start time], [end time], [Time Elapsed]) VALUES " & "(" & Forms("Tech_frm").GO_list.ItemData(selectedGO) & ", '" & Forms("Tech_frm").signin_txt.Value & "', '" & Forms("Tech_frm").phase_combo.Value & "', #" & startTime & "#, #" & startTime & "#, #" & startTime & "#);"
            
            'Loop through selected items in GO_list on Tech_form
            Next selectedGO
            rs.Close
            db.Close
                   
            Set rs = Nothing
            Set db = Nothing
            
            ' Refresh the form to update the log_time_tbl records
            Forms("Tech_frm").Requery
            
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

- Attempt 1:

  ```
  'DOESN'T WORK

  'For Each selectedGO In Forms("Tech_frm").GO_list.ItemsSelected
  'nk = MsgBox("Selected G.O.#: " & Forms("Tech_frm").GO_list.ItemData(selectedGO), vbInformation, "GO#")
  'DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO log_time_tbl (GO_info) values ([Forms(Tech_frm]).GO_list.ItemData(selectedGO)")
  ```
- Attempt 2:

  ```
  'BREAKS HERE Loop through selected items in GO_list on Tech_form.
  For Each selectedGO In Forms("Tech_frm").GO_list.ItemsSelected  

  'Check to see if the tech name, phase, and GO is being pulled
  nk = MsgBox("Selected Tech Name: " & 
  Forms("Tech_frm").signin_txt.Value & "Selected Phase: " & Forms("Tech_frm").phase_combo.Value, vbInformation, "Tech/Phase")
  nk = MsgBox("Selected G.O.#: " & Forms("Tech_frm").GO_list.ItemData(selectedGO), vbInformation, "GO#")            

  'set the value of the GO to a varible name
   selectedGOValue = Forms("Tech_frm").GO_list.ItemData(selectedGO)

  'Insert a new record in log_time_tbl
  db.Execute "INSERT INTO log_time_tbl " & "([GO info], [worker name], [phase], [start time], [end time], [Time Elapsed]) VALUES " & "(" & Forms("Tech_frm").GO_list.ItemData(selectedGO) & ", '" & Forms("Tech_frm").signin_txt.Value & "', '" & Forms("Tech_frm").phase_combo.Value & "', #" & startTime & "#, #" & startTime & "#, #" & startTime & "#);"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Use the actual field names (having underscores) in your SQL:

```
([GO_info], [worker_name], [phase], [start_time], [end_time], [Time_Elapsed])
```

Comment: I made the update and I'm still getting the same run-time error.

Comment: Again, double-check your field names. That error indicates a missing or misspelled field or table name.